Minimum Distance to Fly to Each European Country
Help me plan my holiday. These are all my available flights that I can get on airline points. I'm trying to work out what is the shortest distance to travel if I want to go to each every European country.
routesineurope =Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/fWhrT5Ux"];

GeoListPlot[routesineurope[[;;,{1,2}]],Joined->True,PlotLegends->None,PlotStyle->Directive[Black,Thickness[0.001]],PlotMarkers->Point,GeoProjection->"Orthographic",GeoZoomLevel->4]


Now, for efficiency, I look to change the mathematica entity elements (airport & countries) and instead create a mapping to integers.
(* easier to work with groups/numbers rather than entities*)
(* assign each country a number *) 
countriesineurope = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Join[routesineurope[[;;,-1]],routesineurope[[;;,-2]]]]];
countriesnums = Transpose[{Range[Length[countriesineurope]],countriesineurope}];
countriesnums=countriesnums[[#,2]]->countriesnums[[#,1]]&/@Range[Length[countriesnums]];


(* assign each airport a number *) 
airportsineurope = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[Join[{routesineurope[[;;,2]],routesineurope[[;;,1]]}]]];
airportsnums = Transpose[{Range[Length[airportsineurope]],airportsineurope}];
airportsnums=airportsnums[[#,2]]->airportsnums[[#,1]]&/@Range[Length[airportsnums]];
(* replace with numbers *) 
routesineurope2 =routesineurope/.airportsnums;
routesineurope2=routesineurope2/.countriesnums;


(* group airports into countries *)
groupingrules2={routesineurope2[[#,2]],routesineurope2[[#,-1]]}&/@Range[Length[routesineurope2]];
groupingrules2=GatherBy[groupingrules2,Last];
countrygroups = groupingrules2[[;;,;;,1]];
countrygroups=DeleteDuplicates[countrygroups[[#]]]&/@Range[Length[countrygroups]]

Output: Each group is one country. The challenge is now to work out the minimum travel distance visiting each element in the list.
{{1,81,110,117} (*Poland *) ,{2,3,5,....153,154,155,156,157,158,159} (* UK *) ,{4} (*Gibraltar*) ,{8,11,18,20,28,36,....130,131,132,133,134,137,138,140,141,145,147,161,162} (*Spain*).... 

The flights can now be visualised as a graph:
flightgraph = Graph[routesineurope2[[;;,4]],EdgeWeight->routesineurope2[[;;,5]],EdgeLabels->"EdgeWeight",VertexLabels->Automatic]


How can I determine the minimum distance to visit each country? There are some other covering salesman questions, but the routes involved here make these solutions untenable (computer runs out of memory).

I don't really see how this question is different from the one you linked, other than the fact that you are using a different graph ... Anyhow, what code did you use to get out-of-memory? If I do FindMinimumCoveringSpanningTree[flightgraph, countrygroups], I get {Total[$Failed], {162 \[UndirectedEdge] 123,    123 \[UndirectedEdge] 125, ...}} almost instantly. I don't know why there is $Failed, but otherwise, there is a result at least.

The solution you linked by Ben Izd - does run, however, it does not recover the shortest route for large networks.
For example, see the totally unnecessary dog-leg to the canaries (part of spain, already visited), in your example:
route = Last[   FindMinimumCoveringSpanningTree[flightgraph, countrygroups]] GeoListPlot[  Table[{airportsnums[[i[[1]], 1]], airportsnums[[i[[2]], 1]]}, {i,     route}], Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> None]
https://imgur.com/a/CplxQrO
kglr's solution does work (as a brute force) approach, but cannot be broken down for these large networks.
